# How do I extend a Path Animation curve for a longer fly-through but keep the frame rate at 24 fps?

Tags: animation, timeline

I set up part of a fly-through along a Nurbs path, putting the camera on the path with a Follow Path Constraint, and then added an empty and constrained the camera to Track To the empty. I haven't done animations before, so I fiddled with the points on the path and keyframes placed on the location of the empty until I was happy with it.

Now I want to rough in the rest of the path for the fly-through, which will be several times longer than that first part.

How do I do that so the frame rate won't be changed? I just rolled back to an earlier version because I realized the frame rate had dropped a lot after I changed the number of frames. Do I add in a rough of the rest of the path of the camera first, and then extend the frames on the Path Animation and the Timeline? Is there a place where I can just reset the frame rate?

I should mention I only have 3 more days to get this done, and so I am not betting I can render this out in that time the way I'd like, since I've never done this before and I have gotten used to problems cropping up that bring everything to a halt in these situations. So I really want the playback in Blender to be the right frame rate, so I can use a short cut for now of just screencasting and narrating over that.

Comment: Maybe i'll duplicate the path i have and put in placeholder empties for the spots with keyframes, name them with the frame where they go, and then delete all the animation info there is so far and rebuild it so at least the frame rate is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the curve to be longer, right? Sorry if I misunderstood that part :P

Providing that is the question:

Step 1: Highlight your Nurbs path by pressing right click

Step 2 Enter edit mode either by pressing TAB or by changing it in the 3D View Menu

Step 3: Select the point closest to the direction you would like to go in, then press E for extrude or hold down CTRL and click on the screen, this will add additional vertices to your path which will let the path be longer.

If you have more questions do not be afraid to ask for help :)

EDIT: This fixed @kimholder's problem

Does the Frame Rate become slower or faster when you do this? I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but if it is becoming slower, in my experience it was the viewport not being able to keep up. If its becoming faster, well thats just odd LOL. I think for the timing, you will need to fiddle with keyframes, if it is a visual issue because you are doing viewport playback, try viewing the scene in Solid View or Wireframe View and disable as many other objects as possible

to disable objects, under the Scene View (Top right in regular Blender view) click the eye. Another idea that might be helpful is to move objects to another render layer, to do this highlight objects that aren't as important to your scene immediately and press M, then select one of the other layers and you will see a dot appear. You can quickly access these again and move them back as you wish.

Comment: I do know how to extend the path, but the timing and the frame rate then change.

Comment: @kimholder Does the Frame Rate become slower or faster when you do this? I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but if it is becoming slower, in my experience it was the viewport not being able to keep up. If its becoming faster, well thats just odd LOL. I think for the timing, you will need to fiddle with keyframes, if it is a visual issue because you are doing viewport playback, try viewing the scene in Solid View or Wireframe View and disable as many other objects as possible

Comment: Hm. That makes sense. When i look at it closer, the slow-down isn't consistent. Still i have a big issue of the timing changing a lot when i added on a huge new chunk to the path, but i'll have to deal with that i guess. At least it is only the first section.

Comment: Could you add that comment to the answer? I can't really accept it right now because the help came in the comment.

Comment: @kimholder when you say you added a huge new chunk do you mean the speed of the camera changed after adding additional vertices? Like how far it travels from Point A to Point B? Or that you added more meshes and stuff that slows down the frame rate?

Comment: This scene being flown through is done. I baked most of the textures to help the GPU display it smoothly in real time. I lengthened the path through the scene by a factor of 8. After that the keyframes i'd set up for the empty were useless, the timing had all changed. Now i'm making sure the rest of the path is shaped how i want before starting the keyframe process again. The frame slowdown it turns out was only at the beginning, at a point where most of the models are visible.